# how to publish .net application

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a ASP.Net Web Site in vb.net language. I can debug it and run
it from Visual Studio 2005. I have published it .
But when I want to open this .aspx file in Internet Explorer without Visual
Studio 2005, I have an error

Comment: What version of ASP.NET? What version of Visual Studio? Are you using a database? If so, what version? Where are you publishing to, do you have your own server or shared hosting? Do you want hosting recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can Publish website through click on "Build" menu and then click on "publish website" option. then select target location (where you want to publish your website).

Through above mentioned process you can publish website in asp.net, if you want anything more please let me know.

Comment: yes i know that but proble is how its work on different machin where visual studio is nt installed